# android - how to escape the ' character while saving encrypted text in sqlLite

Tags: sqlite, encryption, java-native-interface, rsa

I am trying to save encrypted data in sqlLite database. So when the entered data is encrypted, some character might change into ' character which prevents the insertion of record in the database.

Now, the problem aggravates as I cannot escape the character by finding it in the encrypted text because if I escape the character then during decryption the output text will get corrupted.

```
char sql[] = "INSERT INTO ";
        //strcpy(sql, "INSERT INTO ");
        strcat(sql, _TABLE_NAME_VALUE);
        strcat(sql, "(");
        strcat(sql, _source_id_value);
        strcat(sql, ",");
        strcat(sql, _command_id_value);
        strcat(sql, ",");
        strcat(sql, _fingerprint_value);
        strcat(sql, ",");
        strcat(sql, _app_id_value);
        strcat(sql, ",");
        strcat(sql, _rule_type_value);
        strcat(sql, ")");
        strcat(sql, " VALUES (");
        strcat(sql, "'");
        strcat(sql, encryptSourceId);
        strcat(sql, "'");
        strcat(sql, ",");

        char temp[1000];
        //itoa(commandIdInt,temp,10);
        //LOGD("Temp value is: %s", temp);
        sprintf(temp, "%s%d",sql, commandId);
        LOGD("Temp value is: %s", temp);
        LOGD("SQL command before copy is: %s", sql);

        strcpy(sql, temp);
        LOGD("SQL command after copy is: %s", sql);
        strcat(sql, ",");
        //strcat(sql, commandId);
        //strcat(sql, ",");

        strcat(sql, "'");
        strcat(sql, encryptFingerPrint);
        strcat(sql, "'");
        strcat(sql, ",");

        strcat(sql, "'");
        strcat(sql, encryptAppId);
        strcat(sql, "'");
        strcat(sql, ",");

        strcat(sql, "'");
        strcat(sql, encryptRuleType);
        strcat(sql, "'");
        strcat(sql, ")");


        LOGD("SQL Insert Query is: %s", sql);
        //char *name = "Name";
        //char *fullname = "My " name;

        //LOGD("%s",fullname);


        // Execute SQL Statement
        //rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, NULL, &zErrMsg);
        if(sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, NULL, &zErrMsg)!= SQLITE_OK) {
            //fprint(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
            LOGD("SQL Error is: %s\n", zErrMsg);
            LOGD("INSERT TABLE FAILED");
            //throw_sqlite3_exception(env, db);
            sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "Table Created Successfully\n");
            LOGD("Table Created Successfully");
        }
```

Note : I am using RSA algorithm and JNI for all the above operations.

Please help !!!

Comment: *All* your `strcat` calls are buffer overflows.

Answer (score 2):

Encrypted text is no longer text but a bunch of raw bytes and as such it is not feasible to store it in a `CHAR`-flavoured database-field.

For storing the (ill named) cyphertext you basically have two options:

1. Use a `LOB`-type column
2. Use Base64 to encode the cyphertext prior to storing it to a `CHAR`-typed column

Either way you should not compose your database-statement by string-composition but use some sort of `PreparedStatement`s instead - so you will not be prone to SQL-injection attacks and don't have to worry over character-escaping.

Comment: Base64 encoding will make data twice longer so way 1 is always preferable to solution 2.

Comment: @divanov: Actually it's 1.3 times longer (3 bytes raw -> 4 bytes Base64). Also LOB-handling might be a bit more cumbersome, so both ways have their merits.